# Does the Saura Purana foretell the appearance of Madhvacharya?

Tags: puranas, dvaita, madhvacharya

Madhvacharya was a Dvaita philosopher who propounded Dvaita philosophy by writing commentaries on Prasthanatrayi. I heard that his appearance was foretold in Saura Purana as an incarnation of a demon named Mukhasura. Now, even [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saura_Purana) on Saura Purana also says chapter 38 to 40 of Saura Purana attacks Madhvacharya. Is this true?

Comment: attacks?  I don't think that's a correct word to use .. why would a Purana attack someone?

Comment: @Rickross That is what the Wikipedia says.

Comment: Okay I thought it was ur word .. U can use block quote then to quote that part

Comment: I have heard that he's advent is also foretold in the Parashara Smriti

Comment: @Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury Parasara Smriti? Not possible. Because it is a law book.

Comment: @NaveenKick Sorry. I actually meant "Parashara Samhita" instead of Parashara Smriti.

Comment: Read https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.59469/page/n63

Comment: Madhvacharya is mentioned in Ballitha suhktham some pragnya athma have deleted my answer so im not attaching the same because the question itself is having hidden intentions..

Comment: I guess the attack is a wrong. The right word should be Truth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Saura Purana chapters 38 to 40 contain prophecy of the birth of Madhvacharya and passages which attack Madhvacharya and his philosophy.

These chapters glorify Advaita and Shiva. There are frequent usage of the six darshanas viz  Sankhya, Yoga, Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Mimamsa and Vedanta. There is even  glorification of Advaita. Not only that, there is also a mention of non vedic schools like Charvaka, Bauddha, Mlechha and Jaina dharmas. There is also mention of Shankaracharya, Badarayana Sutras (perhaps Padma Pada also. I couldn't understand the verses which contain the name properly).

These chapters talk about the characteristics of Kali yuga and prophecies that there would be falling down of all the varnas and the situation would be terrible where Brahmins would be uncultured. In chapters 39 and 40, Suta says the back story of birth of Madhvacharya. According to the story, it is said there is an evil minded person named Madhu who was cursed by his Guru was born as Madhvacharya in southern coast of Karnataka (!).

The curse goes to a very specific detail. It mentions that Madhu will be born will write a commentary on Brahma Sutras. Interestingly *there is exact mention of the name along with birth place*. He would tour countries like Utkala, Maharashtra, West Bengal, banks of Ganga and Godavari preaching his philosophy. As the time in Kali yuga passes, the philosophy preached by him will get popular and the shishyas would be evil too who do Shiva Ninda.

Hence, the Wikipedia claim is correct which says Saura Purana's attack on Madhvacharya.

You can read Saura Purana which is a upa purana of Brahma Purana on wayback machine - **[Saura Purana ASS](https://archive.org/details/SauraPuranaASS/page/n9)**.

Comment: Lol this is why I say these Puranic verses about Adi Shankara, Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and Madhvacharya are interpolated.

Comment: "attack" might not be proper word even if wiki mentions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer What do you call it? I have not mentioned the words mentioned in the Purana. They are worse than attack.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Whatever they might be. Such statements are found in some Puranas. But attack is not proper word.

Answer (score 1):

I request all readers to read this post completely which has all references for the accusations made on Madhvacharya, please click on the links attached and know complete details about this topic. Let us all embrace the factual realities

**Yes. Saura purana, Skanda Purana and even Parashara Samhitha says that Madhvacharya was a demon named Madhu/Mukha who takes his birth in Karnataka's Udupi.**

Irrespective of Madhvacharya being accused as a demon by these shastras, there's one more interesting thing common in all of the three predictions. All three Shastras (Saura Purana, Parashara Samhitha and Skanda Purana) predicted that Madhvacharya will be a horrendous hater of Advaita siddantham and Lord Shiva which is true infact. If you carefully read the works of Madhvacharya like Mahabharata tatparya nirnaya, brahma sutra bhashya etc: you'll find that he had been a terrific hater of Lord Shiva and Adi Shankaracharya's followers. He has done Shiva-ninda nearly more than 250 times in his tatparya nirnaya and has fostered hatred about Shaivas and Shaivism in a magnificent and vicious manner. You can check [here](https:///profile/Vedantashikamani/Madhvacharya-Exposing-the-most-fanatic-and-demonic-personality-in-History-of-Hinduism%20https://www.quora.com/profile/Vedantashikamani/Madhvacharya-Exposing-the-most-fanatic-and-demonic-personality-in-History-of-Hinduism?ch=15&oid=97703841&share=61a91ebb&srid=huaJuO&target_type=post) for all the references from his works.

The **Saura purana and Parashara Samhitha accuses that his disciples will be most evil and horrendous haters of Lord Shiva and Non dualistic practices so that they even step into killing and murdering activities**. How true is this accusation?.

There was a person called Narayan pandit who was one among the direct disciples of Madhvacharya himself. He has penned works like Manimanjari, Madhvamrutha Maharnava etc: where his mindset is clearly understandable.

> **Manimanjari**:- In this vicious work, Mister Narayana pandit abuses Adi Shankaracharya and his family, disciples and lineage in the maximum way possible, like Shankara was a demon, he had Rudravesha, he was killed by Bhima (referring madhva in his previous birth) etc: and also have abused Shankara's beloved mother Aryamba as a prostitute, Shankara as a sex-addict, the one who died because of STD etc: you can find the complete work [here](http://srinivasa-kalyana.blogspot.com/2012/05/manimanjari-of-sri-naryana.html?m=1) where Madhvas have shamelessly uploaded this work with great respect, the most saddest and hindering thing is that these dirty works are being taught to small children of madhvas in their gurukuls, just like how madarasas train Islamic kids for violence.

> **Madhvamrutha maharnava**:- As Saura purana predicts about Madhvacharya's disciples being murderers, it's authenticity and confirmation will be cleared after one read this work. You can find it [here](https://gurucharana.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/madwaamruthamaharnava/).

Talking about other disciples of Madhvacharya like Vadiraja tirtha, Vijayendra tirtha and the famous Raghavendra swamy whom even secular Advaitins and Shaivas worship today, we can know more facts.

> **Vadiraja tirtha**:- This person was a born Advaitin but later was converted to Madhva
> siddantha by people in his village, he in Vayu stuthi abuses Adi
> Shankaracharya and his followers as Jackals, dogs etc: This man also
> criticised female followers of Advaita Vedanta as prostitutes and
> like.

> **Vijayendra tirtha**:- He is another example to completely agree with Saura purana, he's the one who tried to kill Appaya Dixitar who was his contemporary Advaitin rival scholar by appointing killers in Kumbhakonam. This Vijayendra tirtha also have written Shaiva sarvasva khandana where he abuses Bhagavan Sadāshiva is a most horrible way possible insulting Shivalingam etc:

> **Raghavendra tirtha**:- Another famous personality who is considered as some god or deity by some fools was an horrible hate mongerer of Adi Shankaracharya and Lord Shiva. He has written a work called 'Parimala' where he insults Advaitins using abusive language and with a most horrible statement, he ends his work i.e "Lord Shiva gets life and energy by drinking the padarenu (Feet's sweat) of Madhvacharya. But irony is that we'll be constantly seeing many Shaivas of South India also worship this personality unknowingly being influenced by the surroundings.

Irrespective of all these, even Today there are 2-3 official Madhva channels in YouTube where they upload pravachanas of Manimanjari, Madhvamrutha etc: being taught to small children and others. The most surprising element is that neither of the Advaitins or Shaivas are ready to expose this atrocities officially in South India that people get awareness.

Hope it clears everything.

Answer (score 0):

The Saura Purana texts don't talk about Sri Madhvacharya. The text talks about a certain Brahmin named "Madhu Sharma" who was born in Andhra Pradesh (Sri Madhvacharya was born near Udupi, Karnataka). Madhu Sharma is said to be the disciple of Padmapaada Acharya. (Sri Madhvacharya was born 400 years after Padmapaada Acharya). There's too many such historic discrepancies which clearly indicate that this text is not about Sri Madhvacharya. Moreover, there's too many grammatical errors for the text to be authentic. It's more likely that it's interpolated.

Someone has commented in the thread, " In chapters 39 and 40, Suta says the back story of birth of Madhvacharya. According to the story, it is said there is an evil minded person named Madhu who was cursed by his Guru was born as Madhvacharya in southern coast of Karnataka (!). "

This is untrue. Kindly go through the texts once again. Saura Purana Chapter 39 verse 39 states that a wicked minded Brahmin will be born in central Andhra Pradesh. And there's no mention of any southern coast of Karnataka.

For reference,

तदा"न्ध्रीदेशमध्येतु" दाक्षिणात्यो भविष्यति |
ब्राह्मणो दुर्भगः कश्चिद्विधवाब्रह्मणेतरः || ३९.३९ ||

For more info, please go through this rejoinder by Shri BNK Sharma

"AN ATTACK ON ŚRĪ MADHVĀCĀRYA IN THE SAURA PURĀṆA on JSTOR" https://www.jstor.org/stable/41688222?seq=1

Comment: BNK Sharma was a Madhva writer so obviously he'll defend Madhvacharya and his followers.

Answer (score -1):

Harihi Om.

The mentioned section in the Saura Puraana is nothing more than an interpolation, which:

1. Has several factual inconsistencies
2. Is written in incorrect Sanskrit grammar

In the Saura Puraana's 39th chapter and 54th shloka, there a grammatical error:

> तथा तथाऽयमुन्मार्गः शिवद्वेष्टुर्भविष्यति |

The word शिवद्वेष्टुः should have been शिवद्वेष्टा. It should have been in prathama vibhakti, a form of Sanskrit words used to indicate the subject of a sentence, rather than shashti vibhakti, which indicates possession!

Further, there are very basic errors:

- The 30th shloka mentions that "Madhu Sharma" would appear in Andhra Pradesh, while in reality, Shripaada Madhvacharya appeared in Karnataka, with zero ancestral links to Andhra Pradesh.
- Shripaada Madhvacharya's purvaashrama name was 'Vaasudeva' and he accepted sanyaasa under the name 'Aananda Teertha'. He later also became known as 'Purna Prajna' and 'Madhva', but seldom was his name 'Madhu'.
- It was said that he would study under Padmapada, a disciple of Shripaada Adi Shankaracharya, who lived more than 300 years before Shripaada Madhvacharya!
- It states that Madhu Sharma was a Shiva-dveshi, but on the other hand the Maadhva sampradaaya is one of the few Vaishnava sampradaayas with the greatest regards for Shri Rudra, even worshiping him! The Pancharaatra Aagamas recommend sharanaagati and sole worship of Shri Vishnu, as performed by Shri Vaishnavas, but Shripaada Madhvacharya wrote his own Aagama Shaastras to include the worship of Shri Shiva, Paarvati Devi, etc., whose worship is not covered in the Pancharaatras.

Shripaada Madhvacharya even wrote a Shiva dhyaana mantra to meditate on Rudra, while performing sandhyaavandana. Shri Vyaasa Teertharu even wrote Stutis for Shiva. Additionally, Svaami Vadiraja Teertha Shripaadagalu, a 16th century Maadhva Vaishnava even established a Shiva temple at Dharmasthala, which is handled by Tattvavadis even today.

The only basis for the claim about "hatred" towards Shri Shiva by Shri Madhvacharya, is only the interpolation in the Saura Puraana and some misinterpretations of the Mahaabhaarata Taatparya Nirnaya, done by certain online misleaders.

For this reason, Dr. B. N. K. Sharma jokingly stated:

> The interpolator is a fourth-rate Pandit, ignorant alike of history, geography, tradition, art, proportion and philosophy. His only qualification is his prejudice against Madhva.

From this, it is evident that these chapters are interpolations. Additionally, they aren't even found in many manuscripts. Indologist M. Winternitz in his book ["A history of Indian literature"](https://ia801509.us.archive.org/12/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.97551/2015.97551.A-History-Of-Indian-Literaturevol1.pdf), footnotes to page no. 536, explicitly states:

> The Saura-Purāņa would have been compiled approximately between 1230 and 1250. **However, as chapters 38-40 do not occur in all the MSS [Manuscripts], it is more probable that they have been interpolated.**

Professor Julius Eggeling in the book ["Catalogue of the Sanskrit Manuscripts in the library of the Indian office"](https://archive.org/download/india-office-sanskrit-manuscripts-catalouge/IO%20SKT%20cat.%20Vol%201%20Part%206.pdf), Volume 1, Part 6, page no. 1188, stated:

> The work [Saura Purana] has been published by Pandit Kāshinātha Shāstri Lele, in the Anandashrama Sanskrit Series (Poona, 1889). **It there, however, consists of 69 adhyayas, four of which (viz. 38-40, 68) marked by the editor himself as not contained in some manuscripts.**

Therefore, without a doubt, these chapters are interpolations and have been added by some miscreants. The same is likely in the case of other Puraanas defaming other philosophers, such as Shripaada Adi Shankaracharya, which are likely to be interpolated during sectarian conflicts in the recent centuries.

Thank you for reading.
Shri Krshnaarpanamastu.